# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: templates/index.html

Tags: python, flask

[image]I am facing this issue:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: templates/index.html

Although I have made templates folder and put index.html in it, but still I am getting this issue.

My directory structure:

```
/App
   /templates
       index.html
   App.py
```

App.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = 'templates')

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("templates/index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If I make return statement in home() like this:

```
return "Hello World!"
```

It works fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your program is looking for `templates/templates/index.html`. Leave off the `templates` on the call to `render_template`, you already specified the folder the template is in.

Comment: I think that was the problem with my code. Thank you @MennoHölscher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
return render_template("index.html")
```